# Space between paragraphs in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I have a text file with text message(in 5 paragraphs) and the bot that sends messages to Instagram users. But it doesn't put spaces between paragraphs like it is in txt file, just straight text. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with selenium not typing spaces when typing a string, You can use split method and each time you type a string of the new list, you can **send a SPACE** using **Keys** on selenium, like this:

```
parg = "Hello World!"
list_words = parg.split()

for word in list_words:
    input_selected.send_keys(word)
    input_selected.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

I believe something like **this can work too** and it will be better since it won't require using any lists, just one line of code:

```
input_selected.send_keys(parg.replace(" ",Keys.SPACE))
```

**NOTE:**
in order to import Keys in selenium:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```